# Incluir arquivos JavaScript que o teste depende para rodar no MochaJS

Tags: javascript, testes, testes-de-unidade

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em JavaScript do lado do cliente, e quero fazer alguns testes usando o [MochaJS](https://mochajs.org/), só que o teste depende de vários arquivos JavaScript para rodar, que estão em diferentes pastas, como por exemplo:

**Arquivos necessários para rodar o teste:**

```
js/a.js 
js/b.js 

vendor/js/c.js
```

**Arquivo de teste:**

```
test/test.js
```

Minha dúvida seria: qual a maneira mais simples de incluir essas dependências no arquivo de teste.

Encontrei uma forma de fazer isso usando o "require" só que isso levaria a modificação do código para rodar com o nodejs utilizando coisas como "module.exports" e no meu caso o código rodaria no browser.

Outra forma que encontrei foi o "RequireJS" só que nesse caso seria necessario incluir o script em um arquivo HTML, e isso não seria muito útil.

Comment: Os ficheiros exportam variáveis globais de que maneira? É possivel encapsular os ficheiros para funcionar em ambiente Node e Browser, desde que as variáveis sejam exportadas de maneira certa e globais como `document` e `window` sejam chamadas controladamente.

Comment: Da maneira que eu fiz não tenho variáveis globais, tenho apenas arquivos JavaScript com as funções, e um arquivo usa as funções de outro, por isso estão sendo chamados em uma ordem especifica no arquivo HTML para a execução do projeto, só que no teste não sei como referenciar essa dependência que o teste tem para outros arquivos JavaScript, teria uma forma de fazer isso sem modificar os arquivos JavaScript?

Comment: André, conseguiste resolver isto? No MooTools temos um sistema com o PhantomJS que te ajudaria aqui. Se ainda não resolveste dá um toque.